# How do I control a box2d car while in the air?

Tags: box2d, andengine

I have a simple car body with two wheel joints attached and I'm playing around with it, but I don't know how I can control it while it's in the air. E.g. while all wheels are off the ground how can I make it front flip/back flip by touching accelerate/brake. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You could use ApplyTorque to turn the main body.

Comment: Is this a case of finding out when wheels are not colliding with ground and then applying alot more torque to car? because my car already has a maxmotortorque of 2000 for acceleration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Box2d car is controllable in the air. I am trying to get the opposite and prevent controllable car in the air.